# The provided traversal does not map to a value

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I am trying to execute a math query.

```
gts.V()
.hasLabel("account")
.has("id",42)
.both("account_label1").as("label1")
.and(__.identity()
        .project("a","b")
        .by(__.identity()
                .both("label1_label2")
                .both("label2_label3")
                .values("createTime"))
        .by(__.identity()
                .both("label1_label4")
                .both("label4_label5")
                .values("launchTime"))
        .math("floor((a-b)/(86400))").is(100))
.select("label1")
.toList()
```

Above query fails with error

```
The provided traverser does not map to a value: v[137]->[IdentityStep, VertexStep(BOTH,[label1_label2],vertex), VertexStep(BOTH,[label2_label3],vertex), NoOpBarrierStep(2500), PropertiesStep([createTime],value)]
```

1. Why is gremlin injection NoOpBarrierStep?
2. What is the meaning of the `NoOpBarrierStep(2500)`?
3. What will be the correct gremlin query for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `project()` it expects a value for each `by()` modulator and that value should not produce an empty `Iterator`. Here's a simple example:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerFactory.createModern().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6], standard]
gremlin> g.V().project('x').by(out())
==>[x:v[3]]
The provided traverser does not map to a value: v[2]->[VertexStep(OUT,vertex)]
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]
```

The first vertex is able to traverse `out()` but the next one processed by `project()` has no outgoing edges and therefore produces this error. In your case, that simply means that not all of your traversers can traverse `both().both()` or if they can, you would want to be sure that they all had "createTime" property values. Either of those scenarios could cause the problem.

You could fix this in a variety of ways. Obviously, if it's a data problem you could simply fix your data and always assume that the traversal path is right. If that's not the case, you need to write your Gremlin to be a bit more forgiving if the traversal path is not available. In my case I could do:

```
gremlin> g.V().project('x').by(out().fold())
==>[x:[v[3],v[2],v[4]]]
==>[x:[]]
==>[x:[]]
==>[x:[v[5],v[3]]]
==>[x:[]]
==>[x:[v[3]]]
```

Perhaps in your case you might do:

```
by(coalesce(both("label1_label2").both("label2_label3").values("createTime"),
            constant('n/a')))
```

Note that you do not need to specify `identity()` for the start of your anonymous traversals.

Finally, in answer to your questions about `NoOpBarrierStep`, that step is injected into traversals where Gremlin thinks it can take advantage of a [bulking optimization](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#barrier-step). You can add them yourself with `barrier()` step as well. Here's a quick description of "bulking" as taken from the TinkerPop Reference Documentation:

> The theory behind a "bulking optimization" is simple. If there are one million traversers at vertex 1, then there is no need to calculate one million both()-computations. Instead, represent those one million traversers as a single traverser with a Traverser.bulk() equal to one million and execute both() once.